# Android Emulator hangs at [2012-03-21 21:25:09 - <Project>] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have seen this question before but I have tried everything in every response I've seen and none of it works. I have been programming with Eclipse for the past 8 months and have never had an issue, today it randomly quit working.

It just hangs at [2012-03-21 21:25:09 - ] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...   indefinitely.

The emulator just shows that silver pulsing ANDROID lettering. I'm using API 15 and Eclipse Indigo, here is the LogCat the emulator outputs..

```
03-22 01:25:53.494: I/qemu-props(31): connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.

03-22 01:25:53.502: I/DEBUG(33): debuggerd: Dec 13 2011 20:46:49

03-22 01:25:53.632: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..

03-22 01:25:53.632: I/qemu-props(31): received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=192m

03-22 01:25:54.033: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..

03-22 01:25:54.033: I/qemu-props(31): received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=240

03-22 01:25:54.212: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..

03-22 01:25:54.212: I/qemu-props(31): received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=1

03-22 01:25:54.322: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..

03-22 01:25:54.322: I/qemu-props(31): received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=back

03-22 01:25:54.412: I/qemu-props(31): receiving..

03-22 01:25:54.412: I/qemu-props(31): exiting (4 properties set).

03-22 01:25:55.642: I/Netd(32): Netd 1.0 starting

03-22 01:25:55.873: I/Vold(30): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up

03-22 01:25:56.752: D/Vold(30): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)

03-22 01:26:00.622: E/Netd(32): Unable to bind netlink socket: No such file or directory

03-22 01:26:00.963: E/Netd(32): Unable to open quota2 logging socket

03-22 01:26:12.932: D/AndroidRuntime(36): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<

03-22 01:26:12.962: D/AndroidRuntime(36): CheckJNI is ON

03-22 01:26:14.792: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): SurfaceFlinger is starting

03-22 01:26:14.973: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...

03-22 01:26:15.193: D/gralloc_goldfish(35): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

03-22 01:26:15.206: I/gralloc(35): using (fd=11)

03-22 01:26:15.206: I/gralloc(35): id           = 

03-22 01:26:15.206: I/gralloc(35): xres         = 480 px

03-22 01:26:15.206: I/gralloc(35): yres         = 800 px

03-22 01:26:15.206: I/gralloc(35): xres_virtual = 480 px

03-22 01:26:15.206: I/gralloc(35): yres_virtual = 1600 px

03-22 01:26:15.206: I/gralloc(35): bpp          = 16

03-22 01:26:15.206: I/gralloc(35): r            = 11:5

03-22 01:26:15.206: I/gralloc(35): g            =  5:6

03-22 01:26:15.206: I/gralloc(35): b            =  0:5

03-22 01:26:15.212: I/gralloc(35): width        = 74 mm (164.756760 dpi)

03-22 01:26:15.212: I/gralloc(35): height       = 123 mm (165.203247 dpi)

03-22 01:26:15.212: I/gralloc(35): refresh rate = 260.42 Hz

03-22 01:26:15.302: D/libEGL(35): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.

03-22 01:26:15.322: D/libEGL(35): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): EGL informations:

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): # of configs : 8

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): vendor    : Android

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): extensions: EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer 

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): Client API: OpenGL ES

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): EGLSurface: 5-6-5-0, config=0x0

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): OpenGL informations:

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): vendor    : Android

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): renderer  : Android PixelFlinger 1.4

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): version   : OpenGL ES-CM 1.0

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): extensions: GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap 

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096

03-22 01:26:15.512: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096 x 4096

03-22 01:26:15.532: I/SurfaceFlinger(35): flags = 00040000

03-22 01:26:15.594: W/SurfaceFlinger(35): hwcomposer module not found

03-22 01:26:24.082: D/libEGL(67): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.

03-22 01:26:24.142: D/libEGL(67): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so

03-22 01:26:25.002: I/(37): ServiceManager: 0xf958

03-22 01:26:25.294: D/gralloc_goldfish(67): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

03-22 01:26:25.402: I/AudioFlinger(37): Loaded primary audio interface from LEGACY Audio HW HAL (audio)

03-22 01:26:25.402: I/AudioFlinger(37): Using 'LEGACY Audio HW HAL' (audio.primary) as the primary audio interface

03-22 01:26:25.402: D/AudioHardwareInterface(37): setMode(NORMAL)

03-22 01:26:25.952: I/CameraService(37): CameraService started (pid=37)

03-22 01:26:26.212: D/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient(37): Emulated camera list: 

03-22 01:26:26.482: D/EmulatedCamera_FakeCamera(37): Initialize: Fake camera is facing back

03-22 01:26:26.642: V/EmulatedCamera_Factory(37): 1 cameras are being emulated. Fake camera ID is 0

03-22 01:26:27.636: I/AudioFlinger(37): AudioFlinger's thread 0x10ff0 ready to run

03-22 01:26:27.693: W/AudioFlinger(37): Thread AudioOut_1 cannot connect to the power manager service

03-22 01:26:27.722: W/AudioFlinger(37): Thread AudioOut_1 cannot connect to the power manager service

03-22 01:26:27.812: I/AudioPolicyService(37): Loaded audio policy from LEGACY Audio Policy HAL (audio_policy)

03-22 01:26:29.212: I/ARMAssembler(67): generated scanline__00000077:03010102_00000A01_00000000 [  9 ipp] (30 ins) at [0x40aa11e8:0x40aa1260] in 23567034 ns

03-22 01:26:29.242: I/ARMAssembler(67): generated scanline__00000077:03545402_00000A01_00000000 [ 31 ipp] (52 ins) at [0x40aa1268:0x40aa1338] in 5272332 ns

03-22 01:27:38.324: I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(36): Profiling disabled.

03-22 01:27:43.602: I/Zygote(36): Preloading classes...

03-22 01:27:45.934: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 36K, 81% free 408K/2048K, paused 6ms+375ms

03-22 01:27:49.852: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 77% free 472K/2048K, paused 63ms+4ms

03-22 01:27:53.773: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 76% free 508K/2048K, paused 11ms+307ms

03-22 01:28:02.048: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 74% free 535K/2048K, paused 189ms+84ms

03-22 01:28:04.204: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15K, 72% free 575K/2048K, paused 25ms+150ms

03-22 01:28:17.805: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 71% free 602K/2048K, paused 5ms+3ms

03-22 01:28:35.932: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 30K, 69% free 635K/2048K, paused 62ms+46ms
03-22 01:28:37.352: D/TextLayoutCache(36): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0

03-22 01:28:39.792: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioManager$2

03-22 01:28:43.992: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)

03-22 01:28:44.206: D/MtpDeviceJNI(36): register_android_mtp_MtpDevice

03-22 01:28:44.252: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)

03-22 01:28:44.332: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)

03-22 01:28:44.402: W/MediaProfiles(36): could not find media config xml file

03-22 01:28:44.662: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher

03-22 01:28:44.693: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher$Stub

03-22 01:28:47.622: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 19K, 68% free 675K/2048K, paused 22ms+44ms

03-22 01:29:24.442: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 218K, 53% free 968K/2048K, paused 2327ms

03-22 01:29:31.232: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 42K, 50% free 1025K/2048K, paused 12ms+131ms

03-22 01:29:38.785: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 49% free 1054K/2048K, paused 5ms+165ms

03-22 01:29:46.914: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 47% free 1103K/2048K, paused 12ms+21ms

03-22 01:29:57.392: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 23K, 43% free 1169K/2048K, paused 50ms+473ms

03-22 01:30:11.372: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 48K, 30% free 1448K/2048K, paused 77ms+55ms

03-22 01:30:12.392: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$CharCount

03-22 01:30:16.132: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.text.method.WordIterator$1

03-22 01:30:21.583: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 35K, 28% free 1482K/2048K, paused 127ms+79ms

03-22 01:30:32.263: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 27% free 1504K/2048K, paused 636ms+576ms

03-22 01:31:04.232: I/dalvikvm(36): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libwebcore.so)

03-22 01:31:04.292: D/dalvikvm(36): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libchromium_net.so 0x0, skipping init

03-22 01:31:15.272: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 25% free 1553K/2048K, paused 84ms+413ms

03-22 01:31:28.447: W/Zygote(36): Class not found for preloading: android.widget.EdgeGlow

03-22 01:31:35.573: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 23% free 1582K/2048K, paused 40ms+59ms

03-22 01:31:54.242: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 71K, 21% free 1627K/2048K, paused 377ms+509ms

03-22 01:31:57.123: E/PhonePolicy(36): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback

03-22 01:32:03.362: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 20% free 1649K/2048K, paused 70ms+59ms

03-22 01:32:08.672: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 19% free 1677K/2048K, paused 134ms+202ms

03-22 01:32:12.413: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 17% free 1708K/2048K, paused 63ms+67ms

03-22 01:32:17.552: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 16% free 1733K/2048K, paused 238ms+92ms

03-22 01:32:22.213: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31K, 14% free 1761K/2048K, paused 66ms+62ms

03-22 01:32:27.292: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 71K, 12% free 1817K/2048K, paused 299ms+114ms

03-22 01:32:33.352: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 39K, 11% free 1833K/2048K, paused 150ms+160ms

03-22 01:36:04.833: I/System(36): Loaded time zone names for  in 200527ms (199918ms in ICU)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i don't see anything like this. maybe sometimes my emulator didn't loaded, i just close it and run another, then everything work well. 
you can do something like, download newest ADT and SDK or use snapshot for your other SDKs. i hope you can fix that.